# Normal Map showing UV edges

Tags: uv

Please forgive me if this is a really obvious question. I am very new to blender.
I am having great difficulty creating bump/normal map for my model in blender. What I normally do is texture paint then open the texture in Photoshop and generate a bump or normal or both etc.

Usually this works fine however this time the UV edges are clearly visable when the bump/normal is applied. The UV I created was smart unwrapped and this time I did forget to create seams, not sure if that is the problem.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

*Close-up of the issue*

[image]

[Full Image Here. It's a lovely Tarantula spider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAP9q.jpg)

[image: Material Pipeline]

Comment: Set the "Color Space" of the normal map image to Non-Color in the Shader Editor.

Comment: Thanks @FFeller for the reply. I currently have the normal map image texture set to non-color. I will upload image showing my material. Another potential issue that I think could be causing this is that I was originally going to have one texture for the entire spider but I ended up splitting it into one for the body and one for the head. Could this be causing the misalignment in UV?

Comment: May be you have marked Sharp Edges or duplicated verts.

Comment: Hi no marked sharp edges or duplicated verts.